# java script: How can I read html file and load its content to a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to read a html file from client computer and load its **body content** to a div. However, I'm not sure about the correct way to do that. I tried apply these to an uploaded file:

```
   $('#theFile').on("change", function () {
        var file = (this).files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            str = e.target.result;
            slides = new Array(1);
            var pattern = new RegExp(/<body[^>]*>((.|[\n\r])*)<\/body>/im);
            var res = str.match(pattern).join();
            console.log(res);
            $('#slide').html(res);
            slides[0] = res;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
```

The `res` is an array with 3 elements so I joined them together. Is there better solutions which don't engage with regular expressions?

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. What does "local file" mean? Is it local to your website or local to the visitor's computer? You said you were trying to use FileReader, but your example is incomplete. How are you triggering that code? What have you done to debug it (try logging `str` and `res`. You *are* logging `res` but what does it say? You said "I couldn't load the html file from its address" and that you got an error, but **what** error? If it is local to a website then you shouldn't get any CORS error. There are bound to be dozens of duplicate questions for whatever you are doing.

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve? Reading a file selected by the user using a file input or reading a file from a URL?

Comment: When I run the JS, it gives me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags" but you said you didn't get any errors. I had to do some guesswork to fill in the blanks. You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: Re edit: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". Provide a complete [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor to test it.

Comment: @Quentin I could load the content, so I modified my question just to ask if there are more robust solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Add a file-input element to the HTML page:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="readTxT()"/>
And select sample.txt manually:

function readTxT(){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var files=document.getElementById('file').files;
  var f = files[0];
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var text = reader.result;
    $(".diagram").text(text);
  }
  reader.readAsText(f);
}
```

Comment: This is a bunch of code with no explanation as to how it solves the problem.

Comment: The OP says they aren't using a web server and get a CORS error, so this won't work.

Comment: Re edit: You seem to have rewritten the code entirely while throwing out functionality that is in the OP's code. What was the actual problem with the OP's code?